# Make icon for Firefox 24 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, firefox

How does one make a shortcut for Firefox (like any other application that has an icon) that has a command. Firefox 24 run from terminal. Reason I had to uninstall previous version (20) of Firefox was because it was crashing often. This version (24) is stable (and looks like it will continue to be so). I am at present running from terminal:

```
firefox 24
```

Need that I make an icon which opens it and most important overlay menu (like in mac) which is not happening at present.

[image: http://imgur.com/edk0oAl]

Comment: Are you using the unity interface or the classic interface?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the dash and search for "Main Menu". There you will be able to add "New Item". In this window you will be able to put in the command, description and name for you application. If you click the "launcher" icon to the left you can browse for an icon (icons are normally stored in `/usr/share/icons`)

After you have completed these steps you should be able to find your application in the dash, and drag it to your launcher like any other application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Dash Home
2. Type firefox in search bar
3. Drag firefox icon and drop to dash.

[image]